# Actualizar arreglo react js con bucle y axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bucle-for, axios, async-await

Estoy intentado actualizar un arreglo de manera que después de cada iteración se guarde el elemento que me traiga la consulta sin que se elimine el anterior, actualmente lo puedo hacer con el metodo push en un arreglo normal javascript, pero necesito trabajar con un arreglo de react el cual al al hacer setNombre[(...nombre, 'nuevoAgg')] se guarde

```
async function producto(users) {
        (async () => {
            let nuevo_arreglo = [];
            try {
                for (let item of users) {
                    let result = await axios.get(`${urlCompras}/misCompras/${item.productoId}`);
                    setProductos([...productos, result.data[0]])
                    nuevo_arreglo.push(result.data[0]);
                }
                productos.push(nuevo_arreglo[0])
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log(e.message);
            }
        })()
    }
```

users es un arreglo de objetos en los cuales necesito obtener el productoId de cada objeto para enviarlo mediante el metodo get y se me retorne el respectivo producto

Comment: No termino de entender a qué te refieres con un arreglo de react, ¿la linea que no te funciona es la linea de setProductos([...productos, result.data[0]])? Si es así, ¿por qué no haces setProductos(nuevo_arreglo) después del for?

Comment: Concuerdo con @AlexVarela si dentro del for estas añadiendo los productos a `nuevo_arreglo` por que no fuera del for haces setProductos(nuevo_arreglo). Además esto `productos.push(nuevo_arreglo[0])` no tiene sentido, para eso está la funcion.

Comment: yo tampoco entiendo algo... si la funcion producto ya es asincrona, para que creas otra función anonima asíncrona adentro y la llamas ahi mismo? porque no pasar todo ese código a la funcion original?